# Angular-JS ui-sortable bound to model

Tags: angularjs

Let's say you have a list of items that are rendered 3x per row, like:

```
<div ng-repeat="piece in fooService.get()" class="span3">
```

And you want to be able to sort them.  The only way I have found is to wrap with:

```
<div ui-sortable>
```

Which works, but does not bind to the model.

What am I missing?

Comment: I think I am missing two things:  (1) Binding via ng-model, (2) may not work using a service call to obtain data.  Can't bind that way.  The answer to this question may be more along the lines of a better approach to the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to pass the `ng-model` as well:
See the below fiddle i found googling:

http://jsfiddle.net/g/hKYWr/

**Edit**
Reference:
http://plnkr.co/edit/Bzjruq?p=preview

Comment: Because I am using a service to obtain the data, I get:  Error: Non-assignable model expression: fooService.get() (<div ng-model="fooService.get()" ui-sortable="" class="ng-scope">) ... I believe I am messing with two paradigms but don't quite have the solution figured out.

Comment: You can also do '$scope.pieces = $scope.fooService.get();' and then pass the ng-model="pieces"

Comment: Here is a link to a discussion on calling a function in ng-model https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/Pef6LY2rT7g

Comment: "You can also do '$scope.pieces = $scope.fooService.get();' and then pass the ng-model="pieces"" - But that won't reflect the model held by the service.  Seems there is no way around bringing the model to the controller.

Comment: Hey i found a plunker injecting service in the controller. Might be useful http://plnkr.co/edit/Bzjruq?p=preview

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, thank you.  The question should have been "how to keep service-owned objects and controller-owned model in sync", and the answer is broadcast.  I modified the plunker to show service and model in the view.  http://plnkr.co/edit/9TUhw3?p=preview  Add your comment as the answer and I will accept it.

Comment: how can we use with table if i have to move the row.not a cell?